# Validate multiple URLS and get which ones are working

Tags: java, android

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/F4pl0/FARLA) to validate URL within my app but I wanna run the same method for 4 or more URLs instead of one but can't seem to figure out how to.

My code:

```
   validateUrl(this, "https://www.dummy.dummy/");
       SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("url", MODE_PRIVATE);
       if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean("validated", true)) {
           Log.e("WEB",  "RUNNING");
           doSomething():
       } else {
           Log.e("WEB",  "DOWN");
       }


   private void validateUrl (Context context, String URL) {
       new FarlaGetRequest(context)
               .setURL(URL)
               .setListener(new FarlaGetRequest.onGetRequestListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(String response) {
                       Log.e("WEB",  "Done");
                       SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("url", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                       editor.putBoolean("validated",true);
                       editor.apply();

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(int error) {
                       Log.e("WEB", "Failed");
                   }
               }).execute();

   }
```

The goal is, if the url is able to connect (server sent response 200) then do something, else don't.

So what I'm stuck at is, how do I do this for multiple URLs?

Example:

Check 1st (log if it's running or down)
Check 2nd (log if its running or down)
Same for the 3rd and 4th as well.

At the end, it should say which are active and which ones aren't so can someone help me please? ease?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `List` of url's and execute that validator function for the number of times that the size of list is and if the url connects (got response 200) then just move to the next url otherwise remove that url from list. So , in this way you will end up with all the working URL's.

**Solution Code:**

```
 List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();

 // add all url's in the list; for example : urlList.add("https://www.dummy.dummy/");
```

Now we will use a loop to execute the checker function  for all the url's

```
for(int i =0; i<urlList.size();i++)
{
   validateUrl (context, urlList.get(i))();
 }
```

and in the  YOUR_URL_CHECKER_FUNCTION just put a condition that if the server sents response as 200 then do nothing otherwise `urlList .remove("https://www.dummy.dummy/")`

Sample code:

```
 private void validateUrl (Context context, String URL) {
       new FarlaGetRequest(context)
               .setURL(URL)
               .setListener(new FarlaGetRequest.onGetRequestListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(String response) {

// HERE YOU CAN CHECK THAT WHAT'S THE RESPONSE**

  if(!response.equals("200"))
    {  
     `urlList .remove("https://www.dummy.dummy/")`// link to remove
    }

                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onFailure(int error) {
                       Log.e("WEB", "Failed");
                   }
               }).execute();

   }
```

Hope you get that. **Feel free to ask if something is unclear.** And kindly mark it as the correct answer if it helps you so that this answer can help any other needy.

Comment: Check the validation method, please. How would the method know which URL is valid and which isn't.

Comment: Okay in the success listener you are getting a response, so you can check whether it is 200 or not.

Comment: I have edited the answer above, kindly have a look at that. I have mentioned where you need to check and how to remove the URL from list if needed. Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @StevenRõgrê if it worked , then kindly mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: sorry, you still didn't get my question. Let me explain better. The onSuccess listener works when server gives response 200. onError listener works when the server throws timout or any other error. It seems to work fine but what I'm trying is, to run this method for 4 or more URLs at once and then log which worked and which threw an error. Hope you got my point.

Comment: You need to run this one after another or all at once?

Comment: All at once, or one after the other is also fine. The main thing is, it has to log which one failed and which one works.

Comment: You can check in if condition and log accordingly